# Symfony 3.1: Editing form creates new database entry instead of updating

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having problems updating a form containing two entities ("Event" and "Info) in symfony. Everything works fine right up until the user tries to update the information. When they do it's all saved as new database entries.

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Event $event)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $editForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setMethod('PUT');      

    $editForm->add("event", 'AppBundle\Form\EventType');
    $editForm->add("info", 'AppBundle\Form\InfoType');

    $editForm = $editForm->getForm();
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $formEvent = $editForm->get('event')->getData();

       echo "Debug<br />";
       echo "form id: ". $formEvent->getId(); // Wrong. Returns null.
       echo "<br /> event id: ". $event->getId(); // The correct id of entity that should be updated.

       $em->merge($formEvent);
       $em->flush();       
    } else {
       $editForm->get('event')->setData($event);
    }

    return $this->render('event/edit.html.twig', array(
        'event' => $event,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView()
    ));
```

I echo some debug information, and handleRequest() do map the new information into the event-entity found in $editForm->get('event') with the exception that it's Id is missing which I assume has something to do with the creation of the new entity instead of updating. What's up?

Routing:

  `event_edit:
      path:     /{id}/edit
      defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Event:edit" }
      methods:  [GET, POST, PUT]`

Twig:

```
{{ form_start(edit_form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(edit_form) }}
    {{ form_widget(edit_form.event.title) }}
    {{ form_widget(edit_form.info) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
{{ form_end(edit_form) }}
```

Comment: Show us the routing config and the template -- we need to know how the controller receives it's input data).

Comment: Hi Mihai! I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

If event entity is the entity that you would like to update and it managed by doctrine(was loaded), you need to pass event entity to your form. Try this:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Event $event)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $editForm = $this->createFormBuilder($event)
        ->setMethod('PUT');      

    $editForm->add("event", 'AppBundle\Form\EventType');
    $editForm->add("info", 'AppBundle\Form\InfoType');

    $editForm = $editForm->getForm();
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $em->persist($event);
       $em->flush();       
    }

    return $this->render('event/edit.html.twig', array(
        'event' => $event,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView()
    ));  
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem work. $event, at point of persiting, only contains the original data and not the new that was posted in the request.

Answer (score 0):

So since I had also problem with updating the entity - i will leave info for others.

**Symfony Version:** 4.3.x

`$contact_form = $this->app->forms->contact()->handleRequest($request);`

This code simply returns form and then passes request

```
    public function contact(array $params = [], MyContact $my_contact_type = null): FormInterface {
        return $this->createForm(MyContactType::class, $my_contact_type, $params);
    }
```

This will NOT update the existing form. You must pass entity as the data (2nd param).

Now there is another funny thing i learned the hard way.

My rendered view uses **contact_form** and fields from other forms so with this i have a mechanism which extracts subforms from requests and submits them. On the end I got `Request` with original form data.

So now if You do `$form->getData`, You get entire entity build from request. I have modified my view so that i also fill the id form, so with this i have 100% identical entity that already exists in DB - 1:1 compared it.

Persisting such entity built from request will result in creating new entity. **You must** fetch entity from DB to update it.

So this is how i handled that case:

```
    public function saveEntity(MyContact $my_contact, bool $search_and_rebuild_entity = false){

        if( $search_and_rebuild_entity ){
            $id                             = $my_contact->getId();
            $name                           = $my_contact->getName();
            $contacts                       = $my_contact->getContacts();
            $description                    = $my_contact->getDescription();
            $image_path                     = $my_contact->getImagePath();
            $name_background_color          = $my_contact->getNameBackgroundColor();
            $description_background_color   = $my_contact->getDescriptionBackgroundColor();

            $found_entity = $this->find($id);

            if( !empty($found_entity) ){
                $my_contact = $found_entity;
                $my_contact->setName($name);
                $my_contact->setContacts($contacts->toJson());
                $my_contact->setImagePath($image_path);
                $my_contact->setDescription($description);
                $my_contact->setNameBackgroundColor($name_background_color);
                $my_contact->setDescriptionBackgroundColor($description_background_color);
            }

        }

        $this->_em->persist($my_contact);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
```